# getting value of select option then outputs another select option

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to AJAX and PHP, and I have this code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function crimeselect(){
            var select = document.getElementById("crime").value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="crime" id="crime" onChange="crimeselect();">
        <option value="CVPerson">Crimes VS Person</option>
        <option value="CVMO">Crimes VS Moral and Order</option>
        </select>

    <select id="CVPerson" onchange="">
        <option>Homicide</option>
        <option>Kidnapping</option>
    </select>

    <select id="CVMO" onchange="">
        <option>Alarm and Scandal</option>
        <option>Assault/Resistance to Authority</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

What I want is, when I choose "Crimes VS Person", the select option with an id of "CVPerson" would only be the one to appear and the select option with an id of "CVHO" would not be appeared.  Same also if i choose "Crimes VS Moral and Orders".

I don't know how to do it.  Any tips please.

Comment: *Please* read the formatting help before posting code.

Comment: please edit the post with the correct markup for posting code.

Comment: You're on the right track, where are you stuck?  You have the ID of the one you want to show, all you need to do is show that one and hide the other(s).  Here's a hint: use a class for the `<select>`s.

Comment: Right now, it isn't related with Ajaz. Since asynchronus call is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function crimeselect(){

            document.getElementById(document.getElementById("crime").value).style.visibility = 'visible';         

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="crime" id="crime" onChange="crimeselect();">
        <option value="CVPerson">Crimes VS Person</option>
        <option value="CVMO">Crimes VS Moral and Order</option>
        </select>

    <select id="CVPerson" onchange="" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <option>Homicide</option>
        <option>Kidnapping</option>
    </select>

    <select id="CVMO" onchange=""  style="visibility:hidden;">
        <option>Alarm and Scandal</option>
        <option>Assault/Resistance to Authority</option>
    </select>
</body>​​​
```